# Interpretation of the following logistic regression problem

Tags: natural-language, probability, logistic

I have a function that gives the probability of Y=1 given X i.e `P(Y=1|X)=f(wX)`. This function is dependent on variables w and X and I have to give the range of w such that the following condition is satisfied:

There are two points namely X1 and X2.
The question is **"give the range of w such that X1 is more likely to have a positive sentiment than X2"**.

My interpretation is that *"X1 must have a positive sentiment and X2 will not"* since the question can be simply compared with *"X1 is more likely to have chocolate than X2"* which eases my understanding.

As a result, `P(Y=1|X1) > 0.5 and P(Y=1|X2) < 0.5`

However, the solution that my faculty has stated is `P(Y=1|X1)>P(Y=1|X2)` which conforms to the statement *"X1 is likely to have more positive sentiment than X2"*.

Ultimately it boils down to two things:

1- What is the meaning of the statement: "X1 is more likely to have a positive sentiment than X2".

2- Is it different from "X1 is likely to have more positive sentiment than X2"

Kindly elaborate your thought process and help me find errors in any of the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your faculty. First, there is no indication that the probability of positive sentiment given X, `P(Y=1|X)`, needs to above (or below) 0.5 for either case. For example, if `P(Y=1|X1)=0.3` and `P(Y=1|X2)=0.2`, then using 0.5 as a cutoff point will not work. For this reason, any arbitrary cut off should not be used.

Second, in your interpretation that `P(Y=1|X1)>P(Y=1|X2)` means "*X1 is likely to have more positive sentiment than X2*" you are conflating the probability of positive sentiment with the amount of positive sentiment. Y appears to be a binary variable in this case, meaning that sentiment is either positive or it is not. What you are measuring with `P(Y=1|X)` is the probability that there is positive sentiment given X, not the amount of positive sentiment.